# Expression in Spring component scan

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

How can I use SpEL (Spring expression language) in `<context:component-scan/>` tag? Is it possible?

For example Something like

```
<context:component-scan base-package='#{resolver.packagesToScan()}'/>
```

`Edit :
I forgot to place the component-scan tag between backsticks.`

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef-xml-based

Comment: did you manage to get this to work? I couldn't get this to work on Spring 4.3.17. it looks like it never called my bean's function at all, and subsequently did not initialize the beans returned by the function.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this does not seem to be possible - and for good reason.
`component-scan` is part of the XML configuration that creates the Spring context that contains all beans. Referring to beans inside the instruction which tells Spring how create those in the first place is rather circular.

However, "simpler" placeholders can be contained in the attribute, just not "complex" Spring EL, according to the source:

```
public class ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser implements BeanDefinitionParser {
    ...
    public BeanDefinition parse(Element element, ParserContext parserContext) {
        String basePackage = element.getAttribute(BASE_PACKAGE_ATTRIBUTE);
        basePackage = parserContext.getReaderContext().getEnvironment().resolvePlaceholders(basePackage);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

It is therefore feasible to use `${...}` to get hold of system properties, for instance.